# fosuserbundle custom form config in symfony 2.8

Tags: forms, alias, symfony-2.8

When I configure FOS USer Bundle I can set custom form using aliased name in config such as:

```
<service id="my.security.type.change.password" class="%my.security.type.change.password.class%">
        <argument>%fos_user.model.user.class%</argument>
        <tag name="form.type" alias="my_change_password" />
    </service>

 ...

 fos_user:
    change_password:
        form:
             type: my_change_password
```

bun aliasing form configuration is deprecated in symfony 2.8, so what I'm wondering how I could refer a fomr by its name in symfony 2.8 yaml configuration.

Answer (score -1):

use fully qualified class name, for example:

```
<parameter key="my.security.type.change.password.class">FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ChangePasswordFormType</parameter>

<service id="my.security.type.change.password" class="%my.security.type.change.password.class%">
    <argument>%fos_user.model.user.class%</argument>
    <tag name="form.type" />
</service>
```

...

```
 fos_user:
    change_password:
        form:
             type: FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ChangePasswordFormType
```

source: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/configuration_reference.html for FOS User Bundle 2.0 branch.

Comment: To make your answer more useful to other users you could provide an example of fully qualified class name and provide a link to details.